# How can I use a variable in a formula vba excel run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to call upon a variable which contains a cell address in a formula in VBA, but keep getting run time error 1004.  Is the something wrong with my syntax?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/" & CellLocationCFYearTotal & ")* " & CellLocationCFYearDC & ""
```

Or have I not declared the variable correctly?

```
Dim RowLocationCFYearIDC As Long 'can hold over 32000 if over this many rows
Dim ColumnLocationCFYearIDC As Integer 'columns won't exceed 256 in sheet
Dim CellLocationCFYearIDC As String

CellLocationCFYearIDC = ActiveCell.Address
RowLocationCFYearIDC = ActiveCell.Row
ColumnLocationCFYearIDC = ActiveCell.Column
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing R1C1 and A1 styles in the formula.  so change `ActiveCell.Address` to `ActiveCell.Address(1,1,xlR1C1)`  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much Scott, just got back to this and your suggestion worked perfectly as Im sure you knew.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you are debugging look at the value of `ActiveCell.Address`. It is a string. You are setting this to a variable declared as `Dim ColumnLocationCFYearIDC As Integer`. This will not work. You need to declare your variable which will hold your address as either `variant` or `string`.

However, in your formula you use `CellLocationCFYearDC` and `CellLocationCFYearTotal` which are not declared (maybe you didn't paste everything?).

Be aware that you cannot use R1C1 style cell references and A1 style references. You'll need to use `.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` when establishing your addressed.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the detailed answer.  I just got back to this project and your suggestions worked brilliantly.  Much appreciated!